# Trying to implement monitoring for ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis, jmx-exporter

After updating the configuration I'm getting this error while running ActiveMQ Artemis

[image]

add the jmx in `broker.xml`:

```xml
    <?xml version='1.0'?>


      <configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

      <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

       <name>localhost</name>
      
       <server>

        <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>

       </server>     

       <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

       <max-redelivery-records>1</max-redelivery-records>
       <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
```

`artemis.profile`:

```
      rem Java Opts
        IF "%JAVA_ARGS%"=="" (
          set JAVA_ARGS= -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=20000 - 
          XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC - 
          XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Xms512M -Xmx2G - 
         
        Djava.security.auth.login.config=%ARTEMIS_ETC_DIR%\login.config 

    -Dhawtio.disableProxy=true -Dhawtio.offline=true - 
   Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal -Dhawtio.http.strictTransportSecurity=max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload -Djolokia.policyLocation=%ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI%\jolokia-access.xml -Dartemis.instance=%ARTEMIS_INSTANCE% -Dlog4j2.disableJmx=true
    )
    
    rem Add JMX Exporter Java Agent configuration
    set JAVA_ARGS=%JAVA_ARGS% -javaagent:C:\Users\tenal\Downloads\apache-artemis-2.31.2-bin\apache-artemis-2.31.2\lib\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.19.0.jar=9876:C:\Users\tenal\Downloads\apache-artemis-2.31.2-bin\apache-artemis-2.31.2\bin\master\etc\config.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration changes you've made are invalid. This is the problem:

```xml
<server>
   <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
</server>
```

You should use this instead:

```xml
<jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
```

That said, if you want to use Prometheus with ActiveMQ Artemis I strongly recommend use the [metrics subsystem](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html#metrics) and configure the [Prometheus Metrics Plugin](https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). You may run into difficulties with the Prometheus JMX Exporter because ActiveMQ Artemis manages its own embedded MBean server in order to enforce role-based access control.